# Time complexity of a three nested loops?

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity for this piece of code?

```
for(int = n; i > 0; i--){
  for(int j = 1; j < n; j*=2){
    for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
      ...//constant number C of operations
    }
  }
}
```

I find that the two innerloops creates the time complexity of O(n*logn)(?). Together with outer loop this results in time complexity of O(n^2 * logn) for the whole piece of code (?).

According to the answer, the result should be O(n^2) and not O(n^2 * logn).

Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the first for loop runs O(N) times. Lets look at the inner two.

So looking at `j` it will be 1,2,4,8,16 .. n, this means the inner k loop will run

> 1 + 2 + 4 .. + n

times, or written another way

> 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 ... 2^log(n)

you can look up this summation and find its O(2^log(n + 1))) = O(n).

So if we multiply the two inner and outer loops we would get O(n^2)